# Ошибка при деплое функции на MS SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlclr

Пишу пользовательскую функцию для MS SQL Server 2012.
Внутри использую передачу данных по HTTP и сборку `System.Net.Http`
При публикации выдает ошибку

`.Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 10327, Level 14, State 1, Line 1 ALTER ASSEMBLY for assembly 'DatabaseCLRTest' failed because assembly 'System.Net.Http' is not authorized for PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE.  The assembly is authorized when either of the following is true: the database owner (DBO) has UNSAFE ASSEMBLY permission and the database has the TRUSTWORTHY database property on; or the assembly is signed with a certificate or an asymmetric key that has a corresponding login with UNSAFE ASSEMBLY permission.`

Перед деплоем выполнил скрипт

```
sp_configure 'clr enabled', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
ALTER DATABASE MyDataBase SET TRUSTWORTHY on;
```

В MS SQL Managamement в ветку Assemblies добавил сборку `System.Net.Http` c опцией `permission set = Unrestricted`. С другими опциями не позволяет.

Но все равно вылетает ошибка. Если из проекта убрать код передачи через HTTP и саму сборку в `uses` то все деплоится и работает нормально

Comment: Ваша сборка использует "unsafe" скорее всего. Уберите unsafe, он не нужен для http.

Comment: Я для http передачи SOAP и REST использую виндовый ActiveX httprequest - и не подключаю сборки.

Comment: @nick_n_a Забыл написать. Моя сборка использует Safe

Comment: Судя по тексту ошибки - вам нужно зайти в свойства базы, и дать права на "UNSAFE ASSEMBLY permission" юзверю.

Comment: В подобной ситуации мне помогла статья https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/290249/Deploy-Use-assemblies-which-require-Unsafe-Externa Причём метод 1 не сработал, а метод 2 - с созданием ассиметричного ключа - помог.